# The stable category of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-categories, projective-module, stable-homotopy-theory

Is there an alternative description/characterization of the stable module category of Abelian groups? I guess that the category of torsion groups is a subcategory of it, but is it all of it?

What is the structure of the image of torsionfree Abelian groups?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective and also not torsion.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right. I believe that what I need to understand is the image of  non-free torsionfree abelian groups in the stable category. Every cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ will become isomorphic to the zero object.

Comment: In the (projectively) stable module category, the objects are the same as the usual category of modules. The difference is the morphisms. Maybe it's possible to use the fact that M and N are isomorphic in the stable module category if and only if there exists projective modules P and Q such that $N\oplus P \equiv M\oplus Q$?